# How to show that the Ricci tensor is an average over $S^{n-2}$? Ex.8-22, Riemannian Mfds, Lee

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am trying to do question 8-22 using 8-21, which I could do. However I do not see how to apply 8-21.

What I have come up with so far is:

- v is a unit vector. Therefore it is in $S^{n-1}$
- I think, since $v\in S^{n-1}$, we can think of $Rc_{p}$ as an endomorphism $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Thus, a few of the requirements of ex.8-21 are met.

- Do we have that $\int_{S^{n-1}}QdV_{g^{\circ}}=\int_{S^{n-1}=S_{v}^{orth}\ni v} sec(v,w)dV_{\hat{g}}$
- I am not sure how to go from the round metric to the flat metric. Both are induced from the euclidean metric. My guess is that the Riemannian volume form is the same?
- Is it the case that, if $A:=(R_{kijk})_{ij}$ denotes the matrix of $Rc$, then $Q(v)=sec(v,w)$?

Thank you very much in advance.
[image]

Comment: Consider $Q(w) = \pm R(v,w,v,w)$ for $v$ fixed (the sign depends on your convention on the curvature tensor)

Comment: (and restrict $Q$ to $v^{\perp}$, hence the $n-1$)

Comment: @Didier Thanks for the quick reply. Why is that the "associated quadtratic form"? I started with Rc, then used "$g^{km}R_{kijm}$" and then since we have the flat metric $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$, which gave me for the matrix $(R_{ij})=R_{kijk}$. I wanted to use that to show that $<(R_{ij})_{ij}v,v>=sec(v,w)$, by somehow using that sec(v,w)=R(w,v,vw), for unit vectors, but I get nowhere.

Comment: Forget about coordinates. The Ricci tensor is defined by $\mathrm{Ric}(X,Y) = \mathrm{trace}(Z \mapsto \pm R(X,Z)Y)$ or equivalently, $\mathrm{Ric}(X,Y)$ it is the trace of the bilinear form $(Z,T) \mapsto \pm R(X,Z,Y,T) = \pm g(R(X,Y)Z,T)$. Notice that the sectional curvature is by definition $\sec(X,Y) = \pm R(X,Y,X,Y)$ (all signs depend on the convention for the curvature $R$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a unit vector $v\in T_pM$, let $v^\perp\subset T_pM$ be its orthgonal complement with respect to the metric $g_p$ on $T_pM$.

Define
$$
A : v^\perp\to v^\perp;\ w\to R(w,v)v.
$$
Then
$$
Rc(v, v)=\text{tr}A.
$$
(This matches with the usual definition $Rc(v, v)=\text{tr}(w\in T_pM\mapsto R(w,v)v\in T_pM)$ by $R(v, v)v=0$.)

Now $Q: v^\perp\to {\mathbb R}$ is defined by $Q(x)=\langle Ax,x\rangle_{g_p}=\langle R(w,v)v,w\rangle_{g_p}.$
For a unit $w\in S_v^\perp$, we have
$$
Q(w)=\text{sec}(v,w),
$$
by definition since $w\perp v$ and both have unit lengths.
Then by 8-21, we have
$$
Rc(v, v) =\text{tr}A= \frac{n-1}{\text{Vol}(S^{n-2})}\int_{w\in S_v^\perp}Q(w)\,dV_{\hat g}= \frac{n-1}{\text{Vol}(S^{n-2})}\int_{w\in S_v^\perp}\text{sec}(v, w)\,dV_{\hat g}.
$$
(Note 8-21 is formulated in the Euclidean metric $g_0$ on $\mathbb R^n$, but it applies to the tangent space $T_pM$ with metric $g_p$, since all finite-dimensional inner product spaces of the same dimension are isometric by the choice of an orthonormal basis.)

---

**Added in response.** I want to add some details in response to the OP's questions about extending the result in 8-21 from the standard Euclidean $({\mathbb R}^n, g_0)$ to a general $n$-dimensional inner product space $(V, \hat g)$.

I want to show that for $A:V\to V$ with $Q(v)=\langle A(v),v\rangle_{\hat g}$ for $v\in V$, we have
$$
\text{tr}A=\frac{n}{\text{Vol}(S^{n-1})}\int_{S_{\hat g}} Q(v)\,dV_{\hat g}.
$$

Let $\phi:V\to {\mathbb R}^n$ be an isometric isomorphism, that is, $\phi^*g_0=\hat g$. Then consider $\tilde A=\phi\circ A\circ \phi^{-1}: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}^n$. Define
$$
\tilde Q(x)=\langle \tilde A(x), x\rangle_{g_0}.
$$
Then 8-21 says that
$$
\text{tr}\tilde A = \frac{n}{\text{Vol}(S^{n-1})}\int_{S^{n-1}} \tilde Q(x)\,dV_{g_0}.
$$
Note that $\text{tr} A=\text{tr}\tilde A$ since they are conjugate. Now we apply the change of variable formula to show that the two integrals are the same. Note that
$$
\phi: S_{\hat g}\to S^{n-1}
$$
is a diffeomorphism. Also note $\phi^* dV_{g_0}=dV_{\hat g}$. We also compute
\begin{multline}
\phi^*(\tilde Q(x))=\phi^*\langle \tilde Ax, x\rangle_{g_0} = \langle \tilde A(\phi(v)), \phi(v)\rangle_{g_0}=\langle \phi\circ A\circ \phi^{-1}(\phi(v)), \phi(v)\rangle_{g_0}\\
=\langle \phi( Av), \phi(v)\rangle_{g_0}=\langle Av, v\rangle_{\hat g}=Q(v),
\end{multline}
where $\phi(v)=x$.
Therefore, we have
$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\tilde Q(x)dV_{g_0} = \int_{S_{\hat g}} \phi^*\big(\tilde Q(x)dV_{g_0}\big) = \int_{S_{\hat g}} Q(v)dV_{\hat g}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared up a lot! For some reason I took the A as a prompt to look for a matrix.... . To go to the round metric I would apply the change of variable formula as well the rules for pull-backs using $\phi(v)=v$?

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand your question about the round metric. Are you talking about the metric induced on the sphere $S_v^\perp$ from $g_p$ on $v^\perp\subset T_p M$? My last paragraph in the answer was trying to addressing this question. So what you did in Question 8-21 applies here, since ${\mathbb R}^{n-1}$ with the Euclidean metric is isometric to $v^\perp$ with $g_p$. All the constructions are defined in terms of the inner product, there is nothing more to be done when applying the 8-21 result.

Comment: Yes, I meant the induced metric. Why is there nothing more to do? Don't we have two "different" Riemannian mfds, $(S_{v}^{\perp},g^{\circ})$ and  $(S_{v}^{\perp},\hat{g})$? What I was thinking of is 
$\hat{g}=\phi^{*}(g^{\circ})$ (ex.2.42), then using the change of variable formula: $\int_{S_{v}^{\perp}}sec(v,w)dV_{\hat{g}}=\int_{\phi(S_{v}^{\perp})}\phi^{*}(sec(v,w)dV_{\hat{g}})=\int_{S_{v}^{\perp}}sec(v,w)\circ\phi\cdot  \phi^{*}(dV_{\hat{g}})=\int_{w\in S_{v}^{\perp}}sec(v,w)dV_{g^{\circ}}$.

Comment: I was trying to sweep this under the rug by saying they are isometric, so things would match. You can spell out all the details. I would do this before any of the geometric interpretation, so just in the framework of 8-21. Consider how $A$ on $v^\perp$ transforms under your $\phi$, and how the corresponding $Q$ transforms. The change of variable formula does give an equality on the nose as $\int_{S_v^\perp} Q(w)dV_{\hat g} = \int_{S^{n-2}} \tilde Q(x)dV_{g^0}$. Also $\tilde A = \phi\circ A\circ \phi^{-1}$ so $tr(\tilde A)=tr(A)$.

Comment: 8-21 is about equality for the tilted version on the Euclidean metric, now gives the equality for your $(v^\perp, g_p)$. Note that $\text{Vol}(S^{n-2})$ does not change.

Comment: I thought so. ;) Doing it in the framework of 8-21, I would suppose that it is not that much different as I did, isn't it? What do you mean by "on the nose"? Why exactly do you transform A as well? I would say I just "rewrite" the RHS, i.e. the integral, in terms of the metric $g^{circ}$.

Comment: I added the details to the answer.